# SFTP Modification time Permission denied when touching/updating files

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp

The file is apache:apache 660 and username is jdoe and he belongs to groups jdoe and apache.  He SFTPs into the server with WinSCP but when he goes to perform an edit which includes a set modtime command he gets "sent status permission denied" in the syslog.  The file is on an NFS mount (v4) which is mounted rw on this server. How do I deal with this issue in SFTP, RHEL 6?

Comment: The the file in question actually on the server, or is the server providing access to a CIFS mount?

Comment: Gregg, can you improve this Q a bit. It's a little light on details.

Comment: @Gregg - Is it correct to assume that `jdoe` logged in to the server and within the `login shell` he can't modify the file he uploaded earlier thru `sftp`? Can you check the `ACL` of the file by running `getfacl file`? Can you also check the permissions of all the parent directories leading to the file?

Comment: No acl is set, at least nothing that differs from the posix permissions.  He is using WinSCP client and can edit files but receives an error about not being able to edit the modtime.  WinSCP allows you to ignore permission errors, but I was hoping there is a more eloquent server side solution to allow the time stamp update to a group owner member.